# What will be the possible issues with this implementation of Binary Tree?

Tags: pointers, binary-tree

```
class BTNode{
public:
int data;
BTNode left;
BTNode right;
};
```

I just wanted to know the demerits of using this implementation instead of the standard pointer implementation.

Comment: This will work but you would run out of memory very soon

Comment: please explain how?

Comment: Okay, I will add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a node in a binary tree is to store the data and *point* to its two child nodes.

In your implementation, instead of *pointing* to the child nodes you have *stored* the child nodes in the parent node. So basically, the root node contains everything. But the data is replicated exponentially down the tree.

This will result in a severe shortage of memory.

Comment: @jamesgem There are infinitely many options to implement a container. Binary Tree is one of those implementations. And the standard implementation of binary tree uses pointers which is generally used because it does not result in problems like I have mentioned in my answer. You may use arrays or some other container within a node and many other things to achieve the desired functionality but all these are naive.